Disadvantages of posting on arXiv when submitting to Nature or Science?
In astronomy, most papers are posted on arxiv.org before being published in a peer-reviewed journal, partly because the review process is long and timing is crucial to ensure one gets the credit for a discovery.
However, it seems to me (from talking with colleagues) that when papers are submitted to Nature or Science, they are rarely posted on arXiv first. Is it because of the common misconception that journals like Nature or Science will not consider for publication papers that have been submitted to a pre-print server? Or is there some disadvantage in posting on arXiv that overcomes the advantage of claiming the result as soon as possible?

Regarding the journals' policies on pre-print servers, I found this:
Science Journals: Editorial Policies

The Science journals will not consider any original research paper or component of a research paper that has been published or is under consideration for publication elsewhere. We do not regard dissertations/theses as prior publications. We do regard peer-reviewed and citable conference proceedings as prior publication. We support posting of research papers on preprint servers such as arXiv.org, bioRxiv.org, ChemRxiv.org, medRxiv.org, and the like.

For authors: Initial submission – Nature

The Nature journals support the posting of submitted manuscripts on
community preprint servers such as arXiv and bioRxiv. We do, however,
ask you to respect the following summaries of our policies:

The original submitted version may be posted at any time.
The accepted version may be posted 6 months after publication.
The published version—copyedited and in Nature journal format—may not be posted on a preprint server or other website.



Nature and Science have come around to tolerating arXiv, but it wasn't always that way. The cultural memory of academia is quite long.

I don't see any downside to publishing preprints provided the journal won't object, and in this case, they don't. They won't let you post the "as published" version as a preprint, which is pretty common.
Perhaps the colleagues who warn you against this are thinking of "olden days" in which publishers were more strict about such things. That is changing (has changed). Some publishers wish to put submissions on preprint servers themselves, but make that clear in instructions to authors.
And, as you say, it is advantageous to almost everyone to get results out in public early. Not just to assure priority, but to enable extensions.
There is a difference for patentable material (in the US, at least) because of recent changes to patent law. In that case, holding things private prior to filing for a patent is probably necessary.

Everywhere in the world publishing something prevents subsequent patenting. Only in the US has this difference been adapted "recently" (10yrs ago) and only to some extent (1yr grace period). If you want a patent, don't publish before filing.

@DonQuiKong - Other countries with a nominal grace period are Canada and Japan.

In addition to misguided diehard beliefs that are a vestige of the “olden days” that Buffy’s answer refers to but are no longer applicable today, there is a real sense even today in which not posting preprints on arXiv while submitting to a prestigious journal is beneficial to the authors (while being detrimental to the community as a whole). For one thing, authors who delay making their results public until the last possible minute gain for themselves the advantage of being able to continue the research and produce more publishable results without competition for a longer period of time than if they had made the work public earlier.
In addition, publications in journals like Nature and Science are often accompanied by marketing blitzes where the authors try to drum up publicity for their work by issuing press releases, talking to journalists etc. It may be plausible to believe that the media will be more likely to cover your cutting edge scientific research when it’s just been made public now in a Nature publication after being veiled in a shroud of secrecy during the refereeing process, compared to a scenario of a Nature paper coming six months after the results already having been made public in an arXiv preprint. It is natural for people (journalists and colleagues alike) to find new things more exciting than old things.
In other words, the behavior of your colleagues may in fact be driven by rational considerations.
Is it selfish to keep your results secret for as long as possible for maximal career advantage? Yes. Are some people selfish? Also yes. Is the population of ambitious academics (of the sort who aggressively pursue publication of their work in Nature and Science) more predisposed to selfish behavior than the general population of scientists? You can decide that one for yourself...
